# Search box on top like browser

Tags: android

How can I place the search box to stay on the top like in the default browser in android? I don't mean search widget, I mean a search dialog that are persistant on the top of the activity.

Answer (score 0):

You could set different layouts and in the top one you could Set a LinearLayout with `android:height="wrap_content"` and `android:width="fill_parent"`
And set a Parent LinearLayout with weightsum 10 and the Searchbar LinearLayout would have `android:weight="1"`
The second Layout would be with a Weight of 9

So eg:

```
Linearlayout (weightsum=10)
LinearLayout (with searchbar) weight=1
LinearLayout (with the other content) weight = 9
```